# Access a route model from non nested route with Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I am wondering the appropriate way to access a route model from a different non nested route controller.
 If I have my routes set up like this: (this works however, not sure if its proper)

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('admin'); 
  this.route('page1');
}
```

And the Page 1 route has a model like this:

```
App.page1Model = {content:'Content of simple model'};

App.Page1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
   model(){
      return App.page1Model;
});
```

Then the admin controller wants to access the page1 route, I can only do it like this:

```
App.AdminController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    page1Model:App.page1Model,

    Now do stuff with page1Model.....
});
```

Ive tried to use Ember.inject.controller() however that only works for me when my routes are nested and I want to access Parent controller from child. Is there a way to use that syntax to get what I want, or is there a better way than what im doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's an inherent problem with what you're asking for: when the user is on the `admin` page, they're not on the `page1` page, so there's no `page1` context. Some questions you might want to ask:

- what happens if the user goes to `/admin` having never gone to `/page1`?
- what happens if the user goes to `/page1` then `/page2` then `/admin`?

I can think of two *Ember-esque* ways of doing what you want:

1. A Page1ModelService. Here, you create an `Ember.Service` that holds an instance of `Page1Model`. You inject the service into `route:page1` and `route:admin` and let them each pull off the instance. Whether they can change which instance of the model is showing is up to you.
2. Return a `Page1Model` instance in the `model` hook for `route:application`. This route sits above both `route:page1` and `route:admin`, so they can both look up the model as follows:

   // route:application
   model() {
     return App.Page1Model.create();
   }

   // route:page1
   model() {
     return this.modelFor('application');
   }

Comment: Thanks for info @James A. Rosen. The questions you propose should not affect anything. I just want an Admin page to be able to update content on page1. So as long as any change made in admin to update page1 content is reflected in page1, there is no problem. The sequence in how page1 or admin is viewed should not affect anything. I like the first suggestion with a service, I want them both to share the same exact instance so if admin updates, page1 reflects. I have not worked with services before, is that possible to get what I want? I will try now. Thanks again

Comment: Services are great places to store shared state. I recommend trying that mechanism. You can inject the service into the relevant routes and have them look up the right model from the service.

Comment: That is exactly what I did with my response below:      App.register('model:page1', page1ModelFactory);
App.inject('controller:admin','page1Model','model:page1'); And it worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my goal through using registers and injection. Can someone please take a look and let me know if this is 'proper' through Ember standards or if there is a better way ( @James A. Rosen :) )?

OH! If there is a better way to attach the model to the page1 route, please let me know. This worked though I am not sure if i like the .model after create().

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/tikezoyube/1/edit?html,js,output

JS of that:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
var page1Model = {title:'Old Title'};
var page1ModelFactory = Ember.Object.extend({
    model : page1Model
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('page1');
    this.route('admin');
});

App.register('model:page1', page1ModelFactory);
App.inject('controller:admin','page1Model','model:page1');

App.Page1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
    model(){ return page1ModelFactory.create().model; }
});

App.AdminController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions:{
        updateTitle:function(){
            console.log(this.get('page1Model').model.title);

            this.get('page1Model').set('model.title','THE NEW TITLE!');

            console.log(this.get('page1Model').model.title);

            this.transitionToRoute('page1');
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!